# Is there an equivalent to perl's Forks::Super in python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a function which I have to run for approximately 1000 times. Each run takes roughly 8-15 seconds, sometimes even much longer. To save time I want to parallelize that. But not all 2000 runs at once, but for example 50 function runs at every moment. So, there is a necessity of some sort of overarching manager which keeps track of the number of parallel function runs and makes sure that at every momment there are 50 of them active and as soon as a function run finishs, it is supposed to start a new function run to get up to 50 again. I used to do the same in perl using the module Forks::Super. Is there an equivalent to that available in python?

Comment: Tool and library recommendation requests are categorically off-topic here (see #4 in the list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but funny thing is that you used a tag for a standard-library module that has _exactly_ this feature. Note the multiprocessing Pool.

Comment: Cant you utilize the standard library pool abstraction ?

Comment: U're both referring to the package multiprocessing, aren't u? I did some readings beforehand and stumbled accross this package, but I had the impression that it does not provide exactly the thing I want to have. To be honest, I'm not a programmer, I'm just writing sometimes scripts and this stuff is really complex, at least to me.

Comment: Can you add more details for the problem in your question

Comment: @zweiund40, if you don't believe `multiprocessing.Pool` does what you want, write a [mre] that testably demonstrates the difference between what it actually does and what you need it to do.

Comment: I will try. But it will need time. Nevertheless, u guys helped me very much. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. U helped me a lot. My minimal reproducible example works very fine!

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import random
import string

def id_generator(size=8, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
     return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

def f(x):
    sleep = random.randint(8,15)
    time.sleep(sleep)
    return x + ": " + str(sleep) + "s"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = []
    for i in range(42): l.append(id_generator())
    start = time.time()
    with Pool(processes=8) as p:
        print(p.map(f, l))
    print('All in all: {a:6.2f}s'.format(a=time.time()-start))
```

Comment: Of course, I copied most of that together and tampered a bit  with it.